# How to resolve the error "redirect_url_mismatch" on Google API using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to list the files in google drive to a page, while accessing the files, it redirects me to the authorization page but it returns the following error

> Error: redirect_url_mismatch

[image]

Comment: What redirect url you configured at Google while setting up the credentials? Looks its surely not 127.0.0.1. It should match with what you have configured

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you have to use localhost:
`http://localhost:56365/authorize`

This is working in my dev environment:

[image]